# Is there a simple way to search for a string from one dataframe in another df and return an associated value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp

I have two data frames (df1 and df2), each with the columns "Words" and "Frequency". For each word in df1, I want to see if it exists in df2 and then return the "Frequency" value so that it can be appended to include the new instances from df1. And if the word does not exist in df2, then add it.

I have found ways of appending dataframes, but I haven't been able to create a functional loop to do what I have described. I was trying to use Pandas and df.query but had no luck.

In the example below I want it to add the words "This", "is", "test", and "dataframe"
along with their frequency, and I want to append "a" in df2 to be the sum of both frequency values (4 + 222 = 226)

[in]

```
     df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Words': ["this","is","a","test","dataframe"], 
           'Frequency': [20,18,4,12,6]})
```

[out]

```
        Words   Frequency
    0   this    20
    1   is  18
    2   a   4
    3   test    12
    4   dataframe   6
```

[in]

```
    df2 = pd.read_csv("Words.csv")
```

[out]

```
             Word   Frequency
    0   the 562
    1   to  246
    2   a   222
    3   of  204
    4   and 200
```

Comment: are there duplicates in `df2.word` or `df1.Words` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.append` and `groupby.sum`:

```
df2.append(df1).groupby('Word', as_index=False, sort=False).sum()
```

Output:

```
        Word  Frequency
0        the        562
1         to        246
2          a        226
3         of        204
4        and        200
5       this         20
6         is         18
7       test         12
8  dataframe          6
```